# How to get the row count

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Is there an other way to get row count other then counting each row?
I search for a word Selected from ComboBox in Access database and when that word is found, I want to know its row number.

```vb
Dim strBPSSelection As String

strBPSSelection = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE DesignationsList=? "

Dim cmdBPSSelection As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strBPSSelection, Con)
cmdBPSSelection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", DesignationComboBox.Text)

drBPSSelection = cmdBPSSelection.ExecuteReader

If drBPSSelection.Read() Then
```

I want to know at what row I am standing at so I can use that number to get other data from 2nd column of same table and put it in the textbox.

```vb
Dim DadDesignationBPS As OleDbDataAdapter

Dim DstDesignationBPS As New DataSet

DadDesignationBPS = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Posts", Con)
DadDesignationBPS.Fill(DstDesignationBPS, "Posts")

BPSTextBox.Text = DstDesignation.Tables("Posts").Rows(i)("DesignationsList")
```

I want the count to replace that I

Comment: Maybe you mean `DadDesignationBPS.Tables("Posts").Count`? For me, your question is unclear.

Comment: I have a Database called EmployeeDB and it was 3 tables, One of them is called Posts and in that table I have 2 informations 1. is the list of all the Designations and that is called DesignationsList 2. is The grades and that is called GradesList. When I select Designation from the dropdown list it will check that Designation from the Row and i want its Grades to be shown in gradesTextBox

Comment: If you had something like an "Id" column in the Posts table then you could use that. The data in a database doesn't have an order - the results will have an order if you use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: `BPSTextBox.Text = drBPSSelection("BPSList").ToString` I used this line just below `If drBPSSelection.Read() Then` this line of code and it worked Part 2 of the code in my Question was not needed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
            If DesignationComboBox.Text = "" Or DesignationComboBox.Text = "Chose Designation" Then
                DesignationComboBox.SelectionStart = 0
                DesignationComboBox.SelectionLength = Len(DesignationComboBox.Text)
            Else
                Dim drBPSSelection As OleDbDataReader
                Con.Open()
                Dim strBPSSelection As String
                strBPSSelection = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE DesignationsList=? "
                Dim cmdBPSSelection As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strBPSSelection, Con)
                cmdBPSSelection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", DesignationComboBox.Text)
                drBPSSelection = cmdBPSSelection.ExecuteReader
                If drBPSSelection.Read() Then
                    BPSTextBox.Text = drBPSSelection("BPSList").ToString
                    Con.Close()
                End If
                Con.Close()
                BPSTextBox.Enabled = True
                BPSTextBox.Focus()
            End If
        End If
```